# rails: how to dynamically create records and replace value with ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've 3 models:

**Meal** which

`has_many :ingredients`

`has_and_belongs_to_many :products`

**Product:**

`has_and_belongs_to_many :meals`

**Ingredients:**

`belongs_to :product`

`belongs_to :meal`

for Ingredients in Meal I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients`

I want to use model `Product` to store name of product, and in model `Ingredients` I want to use product_id (I don't want to repeat product names, and products will be used for stocks, that's why they have to be unique).

**challenge** aka **question**

I'm creating form where user defines meal name and ingredients - after saving the form, I want to dynamically create product if it doesn't exists and/or use product_id in `Ingredients` and add `product_id` and `meal_id` to the join table (`has_and_belongs_to_many` - meals - products)

So `@meal.save` wont do the magic, how I can do this proper way? should I divide saving only meal  and than do the whole logic for products and ingredients or maybe rails has kind of possibility to do this?

Here is the form:

[image]

And what I get after saving the form (`product_name` is accessor for ingredients)

```
    "meal"=>
  {"name"=>"Mango Chicken",
   "ingredients_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>{"product_name"=>"Rice", "quantity"=>"50", "qty_type"=>"gr"},
     "1"=>{"product_name"=>"Chicken", "quantity"=>"120", "qty_type"=>"gr"},
     "2"=>{"product_name"=>"Mango", "quantity"=>"1", "qty_type"=>"pcs"},
     "3"=>{"product_name"=>"Chili", "quantity"=>"2", "qty_type"=>"pcs"},
     }},
```

Comment: Really find it hard to understand your question. But in Rails, you have the `find_or_create_by` method which does what the name of the method explicitly suggest.

Comment: ah second th' moshun ta repeal HABTM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in a `before_save` callback in the Ingredient model.  The callback would create the product if it doesn't exist, and update the product / meal join table.

If `product_name` isn't a column in your `ingredients` table, you'll need to define it in an attr_accessor.

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :product_name

  before_save :update_products

  def update_products

    return unless product_name.present? 
    self.product = Product.find_or_create_by(name: product_name) 
    meal.products << self.product unless meal.products.include?(self.product)
    meal.save
  end
end
```

But I would STRONGLY suggest you get rid of the HABTM join table.  It's not normalized and so can go "out of sync" with the ingredients... when you delete an ingredient, you'd need a mechanism to delete the HABTM entry.

Better would be....

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :products, through: ingredients
```

and...

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :meals, through: ingredients
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, answer and suggestion - I'll remove habtm relation, your solutions using `through` is much better ;). I totally forgot about `find_or_create_by`, but still before_save filter is very good idea to use it here ;). Thanks